# Open Viewcontroller from Appdelegate REFrostedViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Evening, I just want to open a VIEW CONTROLLER from AppDelegate.

The example which I use > REFrostedViewController / Examples / storyboards /

https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController

My code:

```
//  DEMOAppDelegate.m
#import "DEMOAppDelegate.h"
#import "DEMOSecondViewController.h"

@implementation DEMOAppDelegate
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
  DEMOSecondViewController *NewsTabController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondController"];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:NewsTabController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
}
```

The view controller is opened, however, I can no longer open the menu?

Thank you, Chris from Austria

Comment: Have you tried placing this code in applicationDidFinishLaunching?  Unusual to rebuild the whole UI each time the app comes to the fore.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it does not work

Comment: @ChristopherWeber have you found solution for this am also using the same library